# Essential surfaces in 3-manifold

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, low-dimensional-topology

I am reading about essential surfaces and I know that $F\times \{pt\}$ is essential within the mapping torus of $F$. I also know there are essential tori in $F\times S^1$. Are there other broad classes of essential surfaces?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, of course. What book are you reading?

Comment: I am reading Introduction to 3-manifolds by Schultens and Hatcher's notes

Comment: Ok, then you know about Seifert surfaces for knots and that they are essential in the knot exterior, right?

Comment: Aah yes, for non-trivial knot, their Siefert surface is indeed essential in their exterior that is correct. Are there more broad classes? Thank you so much!

Comment: Yes, absolutely. For instance, as you read more about knots, you learn that not every knot is fibered, hence, not every Seifert surface appears as a fiber in a fiber bundle over the circle. But this is just one class of examples. For instance, you can take exteriors of two nontrivial knots, $X(K_1), X(K_2)$ and glue them to form a closed 3-manifold $M$. The common boundary torus of the above knot exteriors is also essential in $M$. As you continue learning, you will also learn about essential surfaces in Seifert manifolds, graph-manifolds, hyperbolic manifolds...